# Reaction time delay in Flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, delay, timing, stopwatch

I need to measure reaction time precisely with a Flutter app.

The problem I run into is that flutter seemingly can't handle this, and measures my reaction time to around 400 ms, this is about 200 ms too high. I'm not sure if the reaction time is consistant on different devices.

Presumably this is due to some internal calculation of the time elapsed.
I've used the [Stopwatch](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html) class from Flutter to measure.

I would imagine that it's possible to get a more precise calculation of the time elapsed, otherwise how would developers use Stopwatch for measuring function timings.

A abbreviated version of the code can be seen below, i know it's a bit messy.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

  String text = "Wait";

  _setTextBack() {
    setState(() {
      text = "Press now";
    });
    sw.start();
  }

  void _takeReactionTime() {
    int _reactionTime;
    sw.stop();
    _reactionTime = sw.elapsedMilliseconds;
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: "Reaction time = $_reactionTime",
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
    );
    sw.reset();

    setState(() {
      text = "Wait";
    });

    var r = new Random();
    double duration = r.nextDouble() * (6000 - 2000) + 2000;

    print("duration: $duration");

    Future.delayed(
        Duration(milliseconds: duration.round()), () => {_setTextBack()});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(text),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        label: Text("Take time"),
        onPressed: _takeReactionTime,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        icon: Icon(Icons.timer),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I would love some ideas as to how this could be done more precisely.

Thanks

Comment: I think the timer is started when the user opens the app am I right?

Comment: @PythonHub The Stopwatch is started the first time you press the FAB, when the function '_setTextBack' is called that calls 'sw.start();'. This is just some example code tho :)